# Google Direction Service: Estimating U turn at slightest deviation from route

Tags: google-maps

I am using `Google Direction Service` for route drawing by providing it `way points` (recorded at some specific time interval). While drawing, it, sometimes (may be due to slight error in GPS measurement), it draws like the vehicle took a U turn to reach there. I guess it can be solved only if google ignores road dividers.

For example:
Look at the below picture, my vehicle moves on left road, but due to GPS accuracy issues, it sometimes gives me coordinates on right part of road. And when I give the coordinates to google to draw the the path, it gives me a U - Turn.

Can anybody please tell me how can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: You try changin the parameter 'mode=driving' to 'mode=walking' ?

Comment: It is better than DRIVING mode, but it's still not very accurate.